# Grunt-Browserify extensions flag not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-browserify

I am trying to use Grunt-browserify and reactify to parse and bundle React components written in jsx. I want to use the extension flag so that I don't have have to specify the file extension name of my modules, but I have been unable to get this to work. Here is some test code:

A Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        browserify: {
            dev: {
                src: 'src/app.jsx',
                dest: 'dest/app.js',
                options: {
                    debug: true,
                    transform: ['reactify'],
                    extensions: ['.jsx']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify:dev']);

};
```

The main app file `app.jsx`:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var Test = require('./components/Test');   // Here is the problem... 

React.render(
    <Test />,
    document.getElementById('test')
);
```

And then `Test.jsx`:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');

var Test = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
            <p>Some markup</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Test;
```

When I try to compile this by running `grunt`, I get an error:

> Error: Cannot find module './components/Test' from '/Users/****/Sites/grunt-test/src'

The [Grunt-browserify documentation](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) says that it has supported the extensions flag since v1.2.6 and I have seen examples of this all over the web, but I can't seem to get it to work here. If I run browserify from the command line -- like so `browserify -t reactify --extension=.jsx -o dest/app.js` -- it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried moving the properties inside browserifyOptions as follow?

```
grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        browserify: {
            dev: {
                src: 'src/app.jsx',
                dest: 'dest/app.js',
                options: {
                    browserifyOptions: {
                        debug: true,
                        transform: ['reactify'],
                        extensions: ['.jsx']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Couldn't find this documented anywhere... Thanks!

Comment: Why is this still necessary?! And more to the point, how did you figure it out?