# How can I get gulp-bro to import files ending with .jsx?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, jsx

I'm trying to transpile jsx using gulp and gulp-bro, and I'm nearly there except it fails to import components unless I add .jsx to the end of the import. Like this:

```
import Viewer from './components/viewer/Viewer';
```

Fails with `Error: Cannot find module './components/viewer/Viewer'`

While:

```
import Viewer from './components/viewer/Viewer.jsx';
```

Works fine!

Of course the tree of imports is a lot more involved than this, so I'd rather avoid renaming everything to .js or explicitly specifying .jsx if I can avoid it.

Here's the relevant section of my gulpfile. It's ignoring the extensions setting.

```
gulp.task('viewer', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/js/app.jsx')
    .pipe(bro({
        transform: [
          babelify.configure({
            presets: ['env', 'react'],
          })
        ],
        extensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
        debug: true,
    }))
    .pipe(rename('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js))
});
```

Comment: It looks like the extensions must include the "." as in '.js', '.jsx'

Comment: Argh. Yes, that was it, can't believe I missed that... Thanks! Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gulp-bro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bro) passes its options to browserify.  While browserify's documentation on the extension's option is not great, I did see [How to specify browserify extensions in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969318/how-to-specify-browserify-extensions-in-package-json) and [Grunt-Browserify extensions flag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393969/grunt-browserify-extensions-flag-not-working) where the the extensions option must include the "."s like

```
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
```